# If/Else statement labelling features on ArcGIS Online Arcade

Tags: labeling, arcgis-online, arcade

I have an If/Else statement that works fine in ArcGIS Pro but does not work in ArcGIS Online:

```
    if($feature.StreetLength < 3){
return "<FNT size = '8'>" +
Left($feature.PCT_StreetTree_Cover, 4) + "%" +"</FNT>"
}
if($feature.StreetLength > 3 && $feature.StreetLength < 10){
    return "<FNT size = '14'>" + 
    Left($feature.PCT_StreetTree_Cover, 4) + "%" +"</FNT>"
}
else{
return "<FNT size = '18'>" + 
    Left($feature.PCT_StreetTree_Cover, 4) + "%" +"</FNT>"
}
```

[image: Result in Pro]

[image: Result in AGO]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those [formatting tags](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/text/text-formatting-tags.htm) are specific to ArcGIS Pro and are not part of the [Arcade](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/) expression language. Arcade does not support specifying any formatting tags such as fonts or html.